# Multithreaded Shortest Job First Scheduling Algorithm

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, scheduling

I'm familiar with Shortest Process next Scheduling Algorithm (SJF) which is a non preemptive algorithm. But, this algorithm handles only one process at a time which has the smallest burst time. Can it be modified as Shortest Process Next 2 at a time?

So for the example mentioned here:

```
5
A 0 3
B 2 6
C 4 4
D 6 5
E 8 2
```

The first lines denotes the Total number of processes.
The subsequent lines denotes the Process ID, Arrival Time, Burst Time.

The SJF scheduling with 2 processes at a time will works as follows :

```
Time |    A |    B |    C |    D |    E | IDLE |
------------------------------------------------
   0 |   O  |      |      |      |      |   1  |
   1 |   O  |      |      |      |      |   1  |
   2 |   X  |   O  |      |      |      |      |
   3 |      |   O  |      |      |      |   1  |
   4 |      |   O  |   O  |      |      |      |
   5 |      |   O  |   O  |      |      |      |
   6 |      |   O  |   O  |      |      |      |
   7 |      |   X  |   X  |      |      |      |
   8 |      |      |      |   O  |   O  |      |
   9 |      |      |      |   O  |   X  |      |
  10 |      |      |      |   O  |      |   1  |
  11 |      |      |      |   O  |      |   1  |
  12 |      |      |      |   X  |      |   1  |
```

Here,

```
O: Process scheduled
X: Process completed
```

Idle denotes how many processors are currently idle. For this case, there are 2 processors.
It can be observed that at time `t=4`, there are 2 processes scheduled instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a rb-tree and add the tasks to the tree based on their burst time?

The tasks with the least amount of burst time (shortest job) is the left most node in the tree. So when you pick your next tasks, you just remove the left most node from the tree.

When the task completes, you take next task from the rb queue.

When the task blocks, you put it on a separate structure and you take the next task from the tree. You also update the burst time. Once it unblocks, you reinsert it back into the rb-tree.

When a task yields, you update the burst time and reinsert it back into the rb-tree and then take the next task from the tree.

And you can have multiple processors taking tasks from the rb-tree and each will pick the one with the lowest burst time.

The Linux CFS uses a similar mechanism.